# javascript pass by reference workaround

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

let's say I've got an array, `var animals = ["dog","cat","rat"];`

then I define `var pets = animals;`

then I call `pets.shift();`

now because javascript is pass-by-reference for arrays, if I now call `animals`, I get `["cat","rat"]`.

My question: is there any way around this, if I would later like to use `animals` in its unmodified form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A note on terminology: JavaScript is *never* [pass-by-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) (no matter how many times you hear people say that it is). When you write the line:

```
var pets = animals;
```

You're assigning the *value* of `animals` to `pets`. The value that is assigned is a reference to an array, so now both variables *refer* to the same object in memory. (Note: this is a bit pedantic, but it also has the nice property of being *correct*.)

If you want these two variables to refer to two different arrays, then you need to create a copy of the original array and assign a reference to that to `pets`. The most common way to do that in JavaScript is to take advantage of the fact that some array methods (like `slice` or `concat`) create a copy of the array on which they're called:

```
var pets = animals.concat();
```

Proof of in/equality:

```
var arr = [];
arr1 = arr;
console.log(arr1 === arr); // true
console.log(arr1 === arr.concat()) // false
```

Of course, you can also perform the copy yourself:

```
function copy(arr) {
    var i, len = arr.length, arr1 = new Array(len);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        arr1[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return arr1;
}
```

Indeed, [this is probably a lot faster](http://jsperf.com/array-copy/5) and should be considered for very large arrays. (In most cases, just do whatever is most readable.)

Note that each of these methods creates a *shallow* copy of the original array. If the array holds references to other objects, then those references are copied to the new array (i.e. both the original and the new array will refer to the same objects). Strings and numbers, on the other hand, are copied directly into the new array.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer. a subtle distinction which I will have so spend some time wrapping my brain around.

Comment: so - if the copied array contains and object, which is then modified, I could have the same sort of problem.

Comment: Yes. You might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: @GregoryTippett: "if the copied array contains and object" An array cannot "contain an object" because "objects" are not values. An array can only contain a reference (pointer to an object).

Answer (score 3):

You have to clone the array, which is done with

```
var savedAnimals = animals.slice();
```

Note that this isn't a deep clone : it doesn't protect the elements inside against modification (if they're not strings).

Comment: that's the best you have, and that's the standard one.